# Reduce CPU usage of Bitmap.Save

Tags: .net, performance, io, bitmap

I am creating an application that runs on a timer, and each tick I want to take a screenshot and save it to the disk. This should be running in the background, so I want it to take up as little CPU time as possible. However, when I ran a performance analysis, I found that around 40% of the time was spent in `Bitmap.Save` and my CPU usage is up to around 10%-15% on average (it's an old computer)

So my question is, is there any way to throttle the image saving process so that `Bitmap.Save` won't use so much processor time?

I have tried setting `Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;` but that did not change much, and neither did using a thread pool.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    public static void SaveScreenshot(string path)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = TakeScreenshot();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        bmp.Save(path);
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What is the required output file format?  PNG, JPEG, BMP.., ?

Comment: It's PNG. Perhaps it's spending a lot of time on compression?

Comment: Just tested, saving as BMP is about 5-6x faster but also results in 30x larger files. JPEG is about 2x faster and around the same size but it has lossy compression. Is there any way to limit the CPU usage when compressing PNG images, or is this just an inevitable trade-off between performance and image size/quality?

Comment: If you need more performance, it's only one way - try to use some third-party unmanaged libraries for image compressing (for example, libjpeg/libpng). Extract bitmap data (pixel values) using  Bitmap.LockBits then pass that data to suitable function in library.

Comment: I'm not so concerned with the performance as of right now, I would rather simply split the compression task and spread it out across the time between timer ticks so that it doesn't cause spikes in CPU usage. Is this possible without writing my own (or using 3rd party) libraries?

Comment: I guess, that most libraries do compression as one-step action, spreading compression into several steps is very specific kind.

Comment: Is that code running on the UI thread? Is it the CPU usage that you're having trouble with, or the sluggishness in the UI that occurs when the screenshot is being taken and saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the amount of CPU usage required to save the image (while keeping compression ratio and image type). There should be no problem having the compression use all available CPU as long as the thread has low priority. If there is another thread with higher priority that wants to run, your compression will be throttled automatically.
If you run a heavy calculation in another application with normal priority you should see low CPU usage for the compression.

However image compression is not necessarily CPU bound. It could be I/O bound, that is waiting to read/write from/to disk. This is unfortunately trickier to control than CPU bound tasks.